# JavaScript - To know if their is code that will show records for specific dates

Tags: javascript, html, database, web

Right, so I just want to start off by saying sorry if I sound stupid when it comes to anything here as I am very new to JavaScript and working with a database linking to a website.

Essentially I would like a webpage on a site that will show records before a specific date.
Also, is it possible for that date to update every day, for example:
Show only records that are older than 3 months old and that will update daily for that date.

I hope this makes sense to someone and any help that is given is very much appreciated.

Kieran

Code Example:

```
'Where Clause Constructor
    Function queryWhereClause(ByVal orderid, ByVal start_date, ByVal end_date, ByVal name, ByVal status)
        Dim strQuery, dateSplit
strQuery = "WHERE orderdate IS NOT NULL AND orderdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND AmountDue <> '0'"
```

this brings up records that are older than 3 months and that have an outstanding payment on the record but I want to find another page that shows the same page but only shows records that are older than the 3 months stated in the code above of the other page. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you asked "how can i get date in js?".

It's to get today date with format in js;

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
console.log(mm+"-"+dd+"-"+yyyy);
```

You can change variables by adding or subtracting.

It's for get 3 months ago date;

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()-4;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var dt = new Date(mm+"-"+dd+"-"+yyyy);
console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString());
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 3);
console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: Thanks for responding too.  I understand that code for the most part, but what I am wondering if like the code shown above where it will update daily of the day it is showing the 3 months before of can this be done with the code you just showed me.

What I mean exactly is, because that code above updates daily, is there a way to make it so that the other page will show records older than 3 months on the other page and for it to update daily too?  I think I understand to do it without the updating daily, as in it will change the every time to todays date and show the 3 months from that date.

Comment: Yes, I am updating the answer for you. Each time this code runs, it will bring the date you want every day as it will take 3 months before that day's date.

Comment: Ahh right I think I am beginning to understand what you mean now, thank you very much!